# Find $\gcd$ of two polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, divisibility

**Question:** Find $\gcd$ of $x^4+3x^3 +2x+4$ and $x^2-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$

Applying the Euclidean Algorithm as my book suggests, I got the following:

$x^4+3x^3+2x+4=(x^2-1)(x^2+3x+1)+(5x+5)$

$x^2-1=(5x+5)(\frac{1}{5}(x-1)) +0$

However we see that $5x+5$ is not monic. Book says "In that case, multiply it by the inverse of its leading coefficient to obtain the gcd". But in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, $5=0$, so where is the inverse? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you've shown that the first polynomial is divisible by the second.

Comment: @paw88789 Why? Sorry I don't get it. Don't we have a remainder, namely $5x+5$?

Comment: Remember 5 = 0 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make it official, the kicker is that $5\equiv0\pmod5.$