# Use Euclidean algorithm to find the gcd

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, divisibility

$$f(x)=x^3+3x^3+2x+4$$ $$g(x)=x^2+1$$ in $\mathbb Z/5 \mathbb Z[x] $

I got $f(x)=g(x)(x^2+3x+1)+(5x+5)=g(x)(x^2+3x+1)$ as  $5x+5->0$ in $\mathbb Z/5 \mathbb Z$, by long division

I am not sure how to do the long division in a ring/field, for example, if you are in $\mathbb Z/5 \mathbb Z[x] $ the remainder is $4x+9$ then can you reduce it to $4x+4$ or you have to reduce the whole term to $-1x+4$?

Comment: Do [the two of you share a class](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000624/find-gcd-in-mathbbz-5x)?

Comment: The three remainders you have mentioned are identical, use whichever you find most convenient.

Comment: The question is incomplete - what is the second polynomial? If its $x^2-1$, then the question is a duplicate, as Mark remarked.

Comment: Ok thanks, that is helpful